# Shopify - Increment or Counter

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to set up a simple way to increment within `for` loops in my themes and can't figure out how to get it to work.  I'm familiar with two ways to increment:

```
{% assign variable = 0 %}
{% for .....
{% assign variable = variable | plus: 1 %}
.... endfor %}
```

and

```
{% assign variable = 0 %}
{% increment variable %}
```

However neither of these work.  Update: Currently the following block of code will output "0" when it should be "1"

```
{% assign variable = 0 %}
{% assign variable = variable | plus: 1 %}
{{ variable }}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error output?

Comment: The error message was "this page cannot be displayed" after I put that code in the page.  However, that error is not happening anymore.  But I updated my question to further explain the problem

Comment: @Kevmon- Increment in Liquid is weird. It makes its own variable that you can't access anywhere and is, IMO, essentially useless.   See: https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/variable-tags#increment

Comment: The last block of could _should_ be working and is normally how I increment variables when `{{ forloop.index }}` isn't appropriate.  If you have a typo in your code though, anything not-a-number plus a number seems to result in 0 - maybe comb through that part in your live code for tribute to the goddess Tpyos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing with the assign should work however there is an easier way:

```
{{forloop.index0}}
```

See the [docs for the loop object](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/for-loops#forloop-index0)

Comment: Thank you!  I'm getting the results I want now, but I'm still confused as to why the code I listed no longer works.

Comment: the error you were getting implies a liquid error. I don't see anything wrong with what you pasted and I've used the re-assign strategy many times so it should work. But sometimes subtle mis-typings are the hardest to spot.